# How to debug Spring Cloud Gateway memory leak?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have a memory leak in my spring cloud gateway instance which cause in half day to have out of direct memory error in a live environment. I'm not able to reproduce the issue in a development environment. What's the best way to debug data buffer creation and release to know where is this memory leak ? I didn't find anything using JMX to find an indicator of this direct memory usage. What are the logs I can enable to see what happen in spring cloud gateway ?

below my build.gradle

```kotlin
    // Kotlin
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion"

  implementation "com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.18"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.1"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.12.1"
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client"
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

  implementation 'com.atlassian.commonmark:commonmark:0.13.0'
  implementation 'com.atlassian.commonmark:commonmark-ext-gfm-tables:0.13.0'
  implementation 'com.atlassian.commonmark:commonmark-ext-gfm-strikethrough:0.13.0'

  implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
  implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server'
  implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
  implementation "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.4.3"
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'

  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"

  // Enabling caching features
  compile 'org.ehcache:ehcache:3.2.0'
  compile 'javax.cache:cache-api'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'

  compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2"
  compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.11'

  compile('org.jolokia:jolokia-core')

  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

  compile "commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6"
```